# SDL render not working

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have a problem creating this second class in my game, this is a class for player but when I call the texturemanager to draw the play, it's not working, but when i directly call the texturemanager to draw the player it was working. this is my class.

Game.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "Player.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game(void);
    ~Game(void);

    void startGame();
    void init();
    void gameLoop();
    void eventHandler();
    void render();
    void exitGame();


private:
    bool _isRunning;

    SDL_Window* _window;
    SDL_Renderer* _renderer;

    SDL_Rect _spriteClips[2];

    TextureManager _textureManager;
    Player _player;
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Error.h"

Game::Game(void)
{
    _window = nullptr;
    _isRunning = true;
}


Game::~Game(void)
{
}

void Game::startGame()
{
    init();
    gameLoop();
}

void Game::init()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        _window = SDL_CreateWindow("Renderer", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
            640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

        if (_window != nullptr)
        {
            _renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

            if(_renderer!= nullptr)
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);              
            }
            else
                fatalError("Failed to create renderer");
        }
        else
            fatalError("Failed to create window!");
    }
    else
        fatalError("Failed to initialize SDL!");

    // temp image load
    _textureManager.loadFromFile("assets/tiles.png", _renderer);

    _spriteClips[0].x = 0;
    _spriteClips[0].y = 160;
    _spriteClips[0].w = 80;
    _spriteClips[0].h = 80;

    _spriteClips[1].x = 0;
    _spriteClips[1].y = 80;
    _spriteClips[1].w = 80;
    _spriteClips[1].h = 80;
}

void Game::gameLoop()
{
    while (_isRunning != false)
    {
        eventHandler();

        render();
    }

    exitGame();
}

void Game::eventHandler()
{
    SDL_Event evnt;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&evnt))
    {
        switch (evnt.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            _isRunning = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Game::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(_renderer);

    _textureManager.draw(0, 0, &_spriteClips[0], _renderer);
    _player.draw(200, 200, &_spriteClips[1], _renderer);

    // when i used this, it is working
    //_textureManager.draw(200, 200, &_spriteClips[1], _renderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(_renderer);
}

void Game::exitGame()
{

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(_renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(_window);
    _window = nullptr;
    _renderer = nullptr;

    SDL_Quit();
}
```

TextureManager.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <string>

class TextureManager
{
public:
    TextureManager(void);
    ~TextureManager(void);

    bool loadFromFile(std::string filePath, SDL_Renderer* renderer);
    void free();
    void draw(int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip, SDL_Renderer* renderer);

    int getWidth() { return _width; }
    int getHeight() { return _height; }

private:
    SDL_Texture* _texture;

    int _width;
    int _height;
};
```

TextureManager.cpp

```
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "Error.h"

TextureManager::TextureManager(void)
{
    _texture = nullptr;
    _width = 0;
    _height = 0;
}


TextureManager::~TextureManager(void)
{
    free();
}

bool TextureManager::loadFromFile(std::string filePath , SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    free();

    SDL_Texture* newTexture = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(filePath.c_str());

    if(loadedSurface != nullptr)
    {
        SDL_SetColorKey(loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);

        if(newTexture != nullptr)
        {
            _width = loadedSurface->w;
            _height = loadedSurface->h;
        }
        else
            fatalError("unable to create texture from surface!");

        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
    }
    else
        fatalError("unable to load image path " + filePath);

    _texture = newTexture;
    return _texture != nullptr;
}

void TextureManager::draw(int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, _width, _height };

    if (clip != nullptr)
    {
        renderQuad.w = clip->w;
        renderQuad.h = clip->h;
    }

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, _texture, clip, &renderQuad);
}

void TextureManager::free()
{
    if (_texture != nullptr)
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(_texture);
        _texture = nullptr;
        _width = 0;
        _height = 0;
    }
}
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once

#include "TextureManager.h"

class Player
{
public:
    Player(void);
    ~Player(void);

    void draw(int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip, SDL_Renderer* renderer);

private:
    TextureManager _textureManager;
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"


Player::Player(void)
{
}


Player::~Player(void)
{
}

void Player::draw(int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    _textureManager.draw(x, y, clip, renderer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `Game` and `Player` have two different texture managers. The game initializes its texture manager, that's why when you use it directly it works. The `Player` never initializes its manager, that's why nothing is drawn when you use it.

To fix it, you might want to only have one texture manager, the one that is in the `Game` class, and have `Player` just store a pointer or a reference to it. Here's one way to fix it:

Change the type of the `_textureManager` in the `Player` class (but not in the `Game` class) to be a reference:

```cpp
TextureManager& _textureManager;
```

Make Player class accept a TextureManager reference in its constructor, and use it to initialize the private member:

```cpp
Player::Player(TextureManager& textureManager)
          : _textureManager(textureManager)
{
}
```

Make the Game object properly initialize the player in its constructor:

```cpp
Game::Game(void)
        : _player(_textureManager)
{
    ...
```

With these changes your code should now work.